# PHP button executes python script without reloading page

Tags: php, python, deep-learning

I'm building a Web-based UI for my neural network.

Currently, I'm working on evaluating the model and returning the accuracy. I want to have a button that when it is pressed a PHP function executes a python script without reloading the webpage. I want to be able to update the % label with the received accuracy.

My code:

Form button:

```
<form Method="POST" action=""><input type="submit" id="evalBtn" name="AccBtn"></form>
```

Accuracy label:

```
<label id="evalLbl">--%</label>
```

Currently I have been testing the PHP by echoing "Hello World." Once I get the submission working without reloading the page, I'll write the PHP function for executing the python script.

This is the python script I will use to test on and return a value before I run the actual script:

```
testing = 2

def test(testing):
    testing = testing + 2
    return testing

testing1 = test(testing)
```

For clarification, I want a button that calls a PHP function to execute a python script, how can I do this without reloading the webpage when the button is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: Utilize Ajax to do so

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with an ajax request. I would have a RESTful API to interact with your application.

The flow would be something like this:

```
client (browser)                       web server for nn
      | -- POST request to start training --> |
      | <-- ID of this training instance ---- |
      |                                       |
   +->| -- GET status of training instance -> |
   |  |    of ID                              |
   |  | <-- current status of training -------|
   |  |      instance ID                      |
   +--|                                       |
```

You can use PHP to build this API (although I think it'd be easier to interface with the Python NN with a Python web server, like [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org)). You'll have to use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or the newer [`Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) on the browser (or may be just use [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios)).